# Longest Repeating Character In String - Javascript

Tags: javascript, string, algorithm, for-loop

I'm ultimately trying to solve [this challenge](https://www.codewars.com/kata/character-with-longest-consecutive-repetition/train/javascript) on codewars.

I know how to find out how many times a character appears in a string, but not how many times it appears *in order*.

I.e. given the string `bbbaaabaaaa`, we see that the longest repeating character is `a` of length `4`.

I tried a simple for-loop, comparing characters to previous characters to see if they're identical:

```js
function longestRepetition (str) {
  let longestChunk = '';
  for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    let chunk = '';
    if (i === 0) {
      if (str[i] === str[i + 1]) {
        chunk += str[i];
      }
    }
    if (i > 0) {
      if (str[i] === str[i - 1]) {
        chunk += str[i];
        console.log('chunk**', chunk);
      }
      if (chunk.length > longestChunk.length) {
        longest = chunk;
      }
    }
  }
  return longestChunk;
}

console.log(longestRepetition('bbbaaabaaaa'));
```

What's most concerning is that `chunk` is not increasing in size ever whenever I `console.log` it.

Shouldn't we be seeing:

`'chunk**' b`

`'chunk**' bb`

`'chunk**' bbb`

?

Instead, we're just seeing the single characters get logged. Then, my logic is to compare the `chunk` to the `longestChunk` and return the `longestChunk` outside of the for-loop.

Any ideas as to why this isn't working, or what other strategies I should try to return the longest repeating character from a string?

I realize that I will have to format what I return as an array with the character that repeats the most, and the length of it's longest repeat or `chunk`.

Comment: Your set chunk to an empty string at the beginning of every loop iteration

Comment: 1. you reset chunk at each iteration so it won't increase much. 2. you make a special if case in the for loop. If really necessary, do it outside and start your for loop at i=1. 3. you return a string but spec says only length needed. 4. no need to increment every time just keep track of startingSequenceIndex and when sequence is broken, do the substraction. 5.no need to compare [i] with [i+1], just compare [i] with c (the character given in spec)

Comment: You should only empty `chunk` when the character is *different* from the previous.

Comment: Another strategy: https://github.com/khaled301/js-excercise-code/blob/leet-code/long-substring/long-substring.js

Comment: My hint woudl be using a `Map` object as accumulator and `.reduce()` function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is my solution:

```js
function longestRepetition (str) {
  if (str.length === 0) {
     return ['', 0]
  }
  let longest = '';
  let chunk = '';
  for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    if (i === 0) {
      if (str[i] === str[i + 1]) {
        chunk += str[i];
      }
    }
    if (i > 0) {
      if (str[i] === str[i - 1]) {
        chunk += str[i];
        console.log('chunk**', chunk);
      }
      if (str[i] !== str[i - 1]) {
        chunk = str[i];
      }
      if (chunk.length > longest.length) {
        longest = chunk;
      }
    }
  }
  return [longest[0], longest.length];
}

console.log(longestRepetition("bbbaaabaaaa"))
```

Thank you everyone for helping me clean up my code! The key (as @NineBerry pointed out) was to define chunk as an empty string *outside* of the for-loop, and re-assign chunk as a new, single character when it's different from the previous.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use a regular expression to find the longest matching single letter sequence:

```
str.match(/(.)\1*/g).sort((a,b)=>b.length-a.length)[0]
```

Just play around with the following fiddle:

```js
document.querySelector('#test').addEventListener('keyup',function(ev){
 var res=(ev.target.value.match(/(.)\1*/g)||['']).sort((a,b)=>b.length-a.length)[0];
 document.querySelector('#out').innerText=JSON.stringify([res[0],res.length]);
});
```

```html
<input size="40" type="text" id="test" value="aaaabbbbbbbccddddzfffffklxxxaavvvv"><br>
<div id="out"></div>
```

Comment: I don't think it will work much because generally those tests are somehow strict performance wise (O(n) expected I'd guess). I am upvoting for the conciseness though :)

Comment: Hey guys, don't get too uptight. I am well beyond your "test"-phase. This tiny bit of code works. I am not running it on string with length>1000000 ... :D :D

Answer (score 1):

/** Hello, I have borrowed the idea from the last solution and then customized it to serve my purpose. Credit goes to the contributor. */

```
function largestConsecRepeatChar(inputStr) {
    let lrgConsRepChar = "";
    if (inputStr && typeof inputStr === 'string' && inputStr.trim()) {
        function reducerCallback(accumulator, currentValue) {
            if (accumulator.lastChar === currentValue) {
                accumulator.count += 1;
            } else {
                accumulator.count = 1;
            }
            accumulator.lastChar = currentValue;
            if (accumulator.count > accumulator.result.countTracker) {
                accumulator.result = { repeatingChar: currentValue, countTracker: accumulator.count };
            } else {
                accumulator.result = accumulator.result;
            }
            return accumulator;
        }
        const initialValue = {
            result: { repeatingChar: "", countTracker: 0 }
        };
        const { result } = inputStr.trim().split('').reduce(reducerCallback, initialValue);
        lrgConsRepChar = result.countTracker > 1 ? result.repeatingChar.repeat(result.countTracker) : "";
        return lrgConsRepChar;
    }
    return lrgConsRepChar;
}

console.log(largestConsecRepeatChar(" ybtyyrjpy "));
```

Answer (score 1):

Just in case you'd want a shorter version of your idea:

```js
function longestRepetition (str) {
  let longestChunk = '';
  let currentChunk = '';
  for(let i = 0; i < str.length; i++){
     if(currentChunk[0] !== str[i]){
        currentChunk = str[i];
     } else {
        currentChunk += str[i];
     }
     if(currentChunk.length > longestChunk.length){
        longestChunk = currentChunk;
     }
  }
  return [longestChunk[0] ?? '', longestChunk.length];
}

console.log(longestRepetition('bbbaaabaaaa'));
console.log(longestRepetition('b'));
console.log(longestRepetition(''));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could solve this by using reduce on an array from your string:

```js
function longestRepetition(s) {
  const reducer = (acc, value) => {
    acc.count = acc.last === value
      ? acc.count + 1
      : 1;
    acc.last = value;
    acc.result = acc.count > acc.result.count
      ? { count: acc.count, char: value }
      : acc.result;
    return acc;
  }
  const initAcc = {
    result: {
      char: '',
      count: 0
    }
  }
  const { result } = s.split('').reduce(reducer, initAcc);
  
  return [result.char, result.count];
}

console.log(longestRepetition('aaabbbabbaaaabba'));
```

Docs: [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce).

It obviously depends on use-case but, in general, expect reducers to be cheap to run, as they only go through the collection once.

In this particular case, your solution (the for loop) runs all tests in `~230ms`. The reducer function runs them in `~80ms` (with slight variations - ran them 3 times each).
The reducer is almost three times faster.

Comment: If possible, please add a reason for the downvote, so I can improve this and my future answers. Thank you.